# Keyboard & mouse not responding in X11 / XWindows

Tags: x11, lfs, twm

I’ve built a Linux from Scratch (LFS) instance. It is based on version 10 of LFS, it is SystemV based.

I’ve been working on getting XWindows working. When I run the `xinit` or `startx`, XWindows displays without problem. The items that are defined in my `.xinitrc` display on the monitor. I have the twm Window manger installed and it is called/started from within `.xinitrc`.

My problem is getting my mouse and keyboard working with XWindows. The cursor is visible in the dead center of the screen but doesn’t move as I move the mouse. I’m using a Logitech mouse and keyboard that are USB based and connected to the computer via a cable.

I uploaded a few screenshots of my config file, log info to provide some details, please help if you have an idea why this issue exists. The link to these screenshots are at https://postimg.cc/gallery/1y8Ghjx

Answer (score 0):

I got this working. For anyone interested, my solution was installing the 4 of the drivers below.

1. libevdev-1.9.1
2. Xorg Evdev Driver-2.10.6
3. libinput-1.16.1
4. Xorg Libinput-0.30.0

I then ran the “X -configure”, then copied the created xorg.conf.new to /etc/X11/xorg.conf, then ran startx and the mouse and keyboard began working.